# AttributeError: module 'fsspec' has no attribute 'utils' when using to_csv in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to save my dataframe into a CSV file

```
#Create a DataFrame:    
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'LETTERS': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 'letters': ['a','b','c','d','e']})

#Save it as csv in your folder:    
new_df.to_csv('C:\\my\\file\\location\\new_df.csv')
```

This is the error I'm getting:
AttributeError: module 'fsspec' has no attribute 'utils'

Answer (score 0):

First of all see your versions using `pd.show_versions()` because the highly likely case is that the version of `fsspec` is old and therefore is not that compatible with the other pre-installed packages. If the `pd.show_versions()` raises an error, then try update pandas: `pip install pandas --upgrade`. If none of this works, then it is probably a package missing, but I can't seem to find it.